# MongoDB: Javascript out of memory

Tags: javascript, mongodb, out-of-memory

I'm generating some random data in order to store them in mongodb.
By generating a lot of data and storing them first in an array (for seperating the generation from inserting for measuring) an out of memory error occurs.

The code:

```
for (i=0; i<amount; i++)
{                                       
doc = {starttime:get_datetime(), endtime:get_datetime(), tos: null, sourceport: get_port(), sourcehost: get_ip(), duration: get_duration() , destinationhost: get_ip(), destinationport: get_port(), protocol: get_protocol(), flags: get_flags(), packets: get_packets()};
docs[i]=doc;
}
```

I chose e.g. amount = 10.000.000.

all functions look like:

```
function get_flags( )              
  {                                   
     var tmpstring= Math.floor((Math.random()*8)+1); 
     return tmpstring;         
  }
```

How does such an error occurs? How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How does such an error occur? The docs array needs memory so adding 10million entries would mean using up (e.g.) 100x10million bytes (if each doc entry is 100 bytes) which is 1GB of memory.

Proposed solution: Maybe try running the generate-insert cycle in batches of say 1000 entries. So generate 1000 docs, save them and reuse the array for next 1000 docs and so on.

Comment: hmm..the split into multiple cycles seems useful